# how can get previous category from sub category for back button click in iphone in json parsing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I am new to iphone development. I am developing one iphone application like as sms collection from json parsing in that application having
    first  category list like as funny sms, love sms in UITableview
    when click love sms then i get list love sms in uitablview ....after click particular love sms then i display that particular sms in view ...but my problem is when click back option from love sms to  main category it's reponse slow 
    my back button code is

```
-(IBAction)btnBackClicked:(id)sender
{
    btnAddFav.hidden = FALSE;
    btnFavList.hidden = FALSE;

    [self startActivityIndicator1];

    int Type;
    indexId--;
    if(indexId < 0)
        indexId = 0;

    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict1;

    for(int i=0;i<[test.JsonPageList count];i++)
    {
        tempDict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        tempDict1 = (NSMutableDictionary *)[test.JsonPageList objectAtIndex:i];

        if (indexId == 0) 
        {
            tempDict1 = (NSMutableDictionary *)[test.JsonPageList objectAtIndex:0];
            Type = [[tempDict1 valueForKey:@"type"] intValue];
            if (Type == 0) 
            {
                //                lblTitleofApp.hidden = TRUE;``
                btnBack.hidden = TRUE;

                NSArray *arr=[[tempDict1 valueForKey:@"desc"] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
                NSString *subStar = @"|@$:";
                NSString *sub=@":$@|";

                [test.arrTitle removeAllObjects];
                [test.arrnew removeAllObjects];
                [test.arrId removeAllObjects];
                [test.arrImages removeAllObjects];
                for (int i=0; i<[arr count]-1; i++)
                {
                    [test.arrTitle addObject:[[arr objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:NSMaxRange([[arr objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:sub])-4]];
                    [test.arrnew addObject:[[arr objectAtIndex:i] substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange([[arr objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:sub])]];
                    [test.arrId addObject:[[test.arrnew objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:NSMaxRange([[test.arrnew objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:subStar])-4]];  
                    [test.arrImages addObject:[[arr objectAtIndex:i] substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange([[arr objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:subStar])]];
                }
            }
        }
```

how can get privious main category list fastly from particular category ....when click back button 
which concept can i use to solve this problem 
sorry for simple & bad english words 
please giude me

Answer (score 0):

in your main category xib file put your view into navigation controller it has the automatic back button so you dont need code for the back navigation.drag navigation controller to xib and put your view and/or tableview into it.

Comment: back button is not problem ...the above code get solw response from sub category to main category ...

Comment: are you recalling the json on back button?

Comment: ya ....is there any solution to get main category from sub category without executing above code... when back button click

Comment: can you give the code of how you navigate from main to sub category ?try `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in above function write this one line only and check